# how can i increment variable according of number of proprety object

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, object

I have a list of departments, im trying to count how many departments exist for each one, and increment a variable (for ex `i`) so i can call it outside the loop and affect it  as label to each department.

I started by this but it does not work :

```
import publicationTotal from "../data/agora-export-publicationtotal-20210803164942.json";

let stringified, myObj, subkeys;
stringified = JSON.stringify(publicationTotal);
myObj = JSON.parse(stringified);
subkeys = Object.keys(myObj[0]);

let departement= {};
let star = [];
for (let x in myObj) {
  if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(myObj, x)) {
    for (let y in subkeys) {
      if (Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(subkeys, y)) {
        if (subkeys[y] === "Departement") {
          //  star = myObj[x][subkeys[y]] + 1;
            star = departement[ myObj[x][subkeys[y]] ] = departement[ myObj[x][subkeys[y]] ] + 1;
          console.log("dept : ", star);
           
        }
      }
    }

  }
}
```

the publicationTotal file contains this kind of information :

```
[
  {
    "num_dep": "AI",
    "dep_name": "Ain",
    "region_name": "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AI",
    "dep_name": "Ain",
    "region_name": "Hauts-de-France",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AM",
    "dep_name": "Alpes-Maritimes",
    "region_name": "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AM",
    "dep_name": "Alpes-Maritimes",
    "region_name": "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AM",
    "dep_name": "Alpes-Maritimes",
    "region_name": "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AM",
    "dep_name": "Alpes-Maritimes",
    "region_name": "Provence-Alpes-Côte d'Azur",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AG",
    "dep_name": "Ariège",
    "region_name": "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AG",
    "dep_name": "Ariège",
    "region_name": "Grand Est",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AG",
    "dep_name": "Ariège",
    "region_name": "Occitanie",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AB",
    "dep_name": "Aube",
    "region_name": "Grand Est",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  },
  {
    "num_dep": "AD",
    "dep_name": "Aude",
    "region_name": "Occitanie",
    "total_parrainages": 0,
    "color_dpt": ""
  }
]
```

For example, `i` variable will have 4 for "Yonne" department, and 3 for "Val-de-Marne" department.

**Expected result** is to have the department name ans the number separatly, so i can call them where i want

Comment: Share expected result in your question.

Comment: What is the exxpected output?

Comment: @navnath, NItheesh i updated my post

Comment: @MeryemACHEMLAL Is that an Object or an Array. The two answers added here shows the output as an object. What is the change that you are expecting in thore answers?

Comment: i just need to keep the example that i put in my postand have the deparment name and the number separatly, i means in two variables if it possible

Comment: In your example there are 5 departments, So It will be better to keep them in an array or object.

Answer (score 3):

```js
const publicationTotal=[{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Val-de-Marne"},{Departement:"Val-de-Marne"},{Departement:"Val-de-Marne"},{Departement:"Val-d'Oise"}];

let results = {};

publicationTotal.forEach(({
  Departement
}) => {
  if (results[Departement] === undefined) {
    results[Departement] = 0
  } else {
    results[Departement] = results[Departement] + 1
  }
})

console.log(results)
```

Comment: thank you @ksav for your comment :) , how can i get the department name and the number separately, because in the result i have this :  Yonne: 62

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by `get the name and number separately`...

Answer (score 1):

if the department already exits? get it and increment by 1 else set 1

```js
const departments = [{"Departement":"Yonne"},{"Departement":"Yonne"},{"Departement":"Yonne"},{"Departement":"Yonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Essonne"},{"Departement":"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{"Departement":"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{"Departement":"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{"Departement":"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{"Departement":"Val-de-Marne"},{"Departement":"Val-de-Marne"},{"Departement":"Val-de-Marne"},{"Departement":"Val-d\u0027Oise"}];

const result = departments.reduce((acc, item) => (
  acc[item['Departement']] =acc[item['Departement']]
  ?
  acc[item['Departement']] + 1
  :
  1,
  acc),{}
);

console.log(result);

// to get only department names
console.log("departments: ", Object.keys(result));

// to get only no of depatment
console.log("department values: ", Object.values(result));
```

Comment: thanks, there is an error in your result i think, no ?

Comment: What is it? I don't think so

Comment: the last consolelog gives an error, what's the difference between it and the second one ?
`Uncaught TypeError: Object.Keys is not a function`

Comment: I did type mistake there, last console will only give you all dept array of counts, If you want to get result from `result` just do `result[deparymentName]`, It will give you count. I did not understand what do you mean by in different variable, `result` is enough to do any operation.

Answer (score -1):

`Array.reduce` to use the name as key and count as value

```js
const publicationTotal  = [{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Yonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Essonne"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Seine-Saint-Denis"},{Departement:"Val-de-Marne"},{Departement:"Val-de-Marne"},{Departement:"Val-de-Marne"},{Departement:"Val-d'Oise"}];
const output = publicationTotal.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  acc[curr.Departement] ? acc[curr.Departement]++ : acc[curr.Departement] = 1;
  return acc;
}, {});
console.log(output);
```

Comment: don't you think that is heavy when we have a file with 2000 department or plus for each one ?

Comment: @MeryemACHEMLAL Anyhow you have to execye a loop to segregate the result